# CarrierWave/Mongoid: Copy File from one record to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, carrierwave, gridfs

We have the following Models:

- Template
- Document

Both have a CarrierWave Uploader mounted with which I can attach files to a record. The files are stored in MongoDB's GridFS. That works fine.

The user should then be able to create a new `Document` using a `Template`. That means that the file which is attached to `Template` should be copied to the newly created `Document` object.

I use the follwing code for copying the file:

```
template = Template.find(tmpl_id)
new_document = Document.new
new_document.source = template.source.file
```

`source` is the attribute where the carrierwave uploader is mounted on. This sample actually works. But only for files which are not larger then one GridFS-chunk. Larger files are not copied. That means the target file stays at a size of 0 Bytes although I get no error message.

CarrierWave is included in our Gemfile like this:

```
gem "carrierwave-mongoid", '0.3.0.alpha', git: "git://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave-mongoid.git", branch: "mongoid-3.0"
```

(The real world is a bit more complicated. I simplifed some things here to stay focused on the problem.)

Does anyone have some examples or best-practice on how to copy files from one record/model to another using CarrierWave and GridFS?